# Weapons disabled order in FTL?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I remember that the weapons order affects the order it is disabled if the weapons is partially damaged, but can't seem to remember if it's disabled from 1 to .., or the opposite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The leftmost weapons will remain on if possible when power is limited. Put your most important weapons there.